# In what order filter applied in Solr and ways to control this?

Tags: solr, filter, lucene

I understand semantics: first we execute query and then we apply filters as DocIdSets(tring to get them from cache).

For some queries it is very inefficient, for example if main query is complex double function of all documents(sqrt(popularity) + distance(...)), at first I will evaluate this function for all index and then filter it...

Is there a way to run original query on filtered doc id set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> first we execute query and then we apply filters as DocIdSets(tring to get them from cache).

This is not true, Solr only computes the required scores, meaning that if any filter doesn't match a document, the score for this document won't be computed.

However it is true that it requires to perform disk accesses. In order to prevent this, Solr has the [useFilterForSortedQuery](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#useFilterForSortedQuery) option that will first fetch the DocSet in the cache if available and then sort it in memory. I guess that it is what you were looking for.

Comment: Solr caching is complex and has a lot of options, but Yonik wrote a very interesting blog post about it that I encourage reading. http://yonik.com/posts/advanced-filter-caching-in-solr/

Comment: Nice article, thanks. However it is still unclear in which order non-cached filters executed. Seems it is important since intersection between large DocSet and smaller DocSet is slower then vise versa. I have question about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078938/how-solr-filters-actually-implemented

Comment: @jpountz I am trying to understand the basics/purpose of useFilterForSortedQuery. Can you point me to some better doc for reference? 

I also notice that Yonik Seeley had long back mentioned on solr thread to avoid using it and it is still marked commented in solrconfig.xml.  (https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/200612.mbox/%3Cc68e39170612111403g39e482fbke3017155a85f0791@mail.gmail.com%3E)